# MVC View Page not showing Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Model class is below:
I have three classes two of them are partial class and one is simple class.......

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RegistrationMetaData))]
public partial class Registration
{              
}

public class RegistrationMetaData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ImagesMetaData))]
public partial class Images
{
}

public class ImagesMetaData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string stuid { get; set; }
    public string stuimg1 { get; set; }               
    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string stuimg1 { get; set; }                  
}

public class NotificationViewModel
{
    public Registration registration { get; set; }
    public Notification notification { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeViewModel { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have used the below code in controller class to fetch Images record with foreign key in registration table.

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> model1 = null;
model1 = (from e in db.Registrations  
          join j in db.Images on e.Id equals j.stuid  
          where e.Email == Email  
          select new EmployeeViewModel  
          {  
              Name = e.Name,  
              stuimg1 = j.stuimg1                                    
          }).ToList();  


var mixmodel = new NotificationViewModel  
{  
    EmployeeViewModel = model1  
};  

return View(mixmodel);
```

Atlast my view page is like this:-

```
@model IEnumerable<Amar.Models.NotificationViewModel>  

@foreach (var item in Model)  
{  
    @item.EmployeeViewModel.stuimg1            
}
```

But I am getting an error

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'stuimg1' and no extension method 'stuimg1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have gone through debugging my code is fine till controller page...but from view page the values are not showing.I think there is some little mistake i have made...

Please someone help me..I am trying to solve this problem since 2 weeks....

I want to fetch data from one more class on the same view page thats why I am using NotificationViewModel class.

Answer (score 2):

```
return View(mixmodel);
```

Your view is expecting a type of `IEnumerable<NotificationViewModel>` but mixmodel is just a `NotificationViewModel`

I'm not seeing what you are achieving by having this additional class 'NotificationViewModel'. If your view were to be changed to expect an `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModal>` you could pass in model1 directly.

You could then change your view to:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)  
{  
    @item.stuimg1            
}
```

If you do indeed need this extra layer of abstraction for some other part of your view then you need to sit and think about what is a a single instance and what is a list. Try drawing it if you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks Chris...Actually I want some other class also on the same view page thats why..I am adding that NotificationViewModel class.Give any Idea..because my mind is blocked...